# using lambda do define hash function throws exception

Tags: c++, hash, c++11, std, unordered-set

The following code defines a `unordered_set`.
The code compiles just fine.
But using the lambda function instead of functor throw when calling find:

> libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception

```
#include <unordered_set>

class pair_hash {
    public:
        size_t operator() (const std::pair<int, int> &x) const {
            return std::hash<int>()(x.first) ^ std::hash<int>()(x.second);
        }
};

int main() {
    std::unordered_set<std::pair<int, int>, pair_hash> temp;
    temp.find(std::make_pair(0,0));


    std::function<std::size_t(std::pair<int , int>)> fpair_hash;
    fpair_hash = [](const std::pair<int, int>& v) -> std::size_t
    {
        return std::hash<int>()(v.first) ^ std::hash<int>()(v.second);
    };

    std::unordered_set<std::pair<int, int>, decltype(fpair_hash)> temp2;
    //why does this not work?
    temp2.find(std::make_pair(0,0));
    return 0;
}
```

> clang++ -std=c++11 -stdlib=libc++ -o test test.cpp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`decltype(fpair_hash)` is `std::function<std::size_t(std::pair<int , int>)>` so you are just building set with empty hash function.

You need to provide your function to constructor of `std::unordered_set`:

```
std::unordered_set<std::pair<int, int>, decltype(fpair_hash)> temp2(10, fpair_hash);
```

This should make it work, but using `std::function` will have overhead of polymorphic call and you probably don't need it:

```
auto fpair_hash = [](const std::pair<int, int>& v) -> std::size_t
{
    return std::hash<int>()(v.first) ^ std::hash<int>()(v.second);
};
```

Finally, your hash function is not really good - it maps all pairs `(x, x)` to `0`. Perhaps using something like `x * 17 + y * 13` instead of `x ^ y` will reduce probability of collisions.

Comment: I would argue for `return std::hash<int>()(std::hash<int>()(v.first) ^ v.second);`